# Animation not always visible from animateTransition in UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am using some `UIViewController`s contained in a `UINavigationController`.

One is presented with a push `segue` from a `UIButton` on the `storyboard`, and is then dismissed using a swipe gesture which calls

```
popViewControllerAnimated
```

I'm using a `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to provide a custom object which conforms to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. The code for animateTransition is shown below.

My problem is that the first time this runs, the view animates in when presenting, but every time after that, it doesn't animate (it just appears instantly).

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

```
-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

//Get references to the view hierarchy
UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];


if (self.isPresenting) {

    [containerView insertSubview:toViewController.view belowSubview:fromViewController.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-1000, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];

} else if (!self.isPresenting) {
    //Add 'to' view to the hierarchy
    [containerView insertSubview:toViewController.view belowSubview:fromViewController.view];

    //Scale the 'from' view down until it disappears
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        //toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
        fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar set of issues after upgrading to iOS8. A few things to check:

1. Make sure to call these before starting the animations:

   `[toViewController beginAppearanceTransition:YES animated:YES];
    [fromViewController beginAppearanceTransition:NO animated:YES];`
2. Then call these in the completion block:

   `[toViewController endAppearanceTransition];
   [fromViewController endAppearanceTransition];
   [transitionContext completeTransition:finished];`

The above is needed to ensure viewWillAppear: and viewWillDisappear: are called at the right times.

3. Set modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen, instead of UIModalPresentationCustom (which behaves very differently).

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful setting `self.navigationController.delegate`

you probably place it in somewhere that only runs once like **ViewDidLoad**
try placing it in **ViewDidAppear**

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController.delegate = self
    }
```

Comment: It's already in viewWillAppear, Sorry I should note.. the code above for the animation does actually get called (I've verified with NSLog statements) but the animation itself doesn't actually happen after the first time

Comment: Maybe u can push your sample project to github

Comment: I might try that later today if I get a chance. I think it may have something to do with the view controller already being in memory during the second transition..